# XPages bootstrap break(small space) between table and inputBox

Tags: css, xpages

I have **Bootstrap 3.2.0**. When I put a `table` into a page (.xsp) it takes so much space there.

I tried all bootstrap classes like `table-condensed`, `table-responsive` etc. for **tables** and `input-sm`, `form-control` and the others for **inputboxes**.

I created a **CSS** class shown below and then even if I use those classes nothing changed.

**Expected result:**

I'm looking for a solution on how to make whole spaces between *inputBox* and *table* to disappear.

```
.input-group-xs>.form-control, .input-group-xs>.input-group-addon, .input-group-xs>.input-group-btn>.btn { 
    height: 22px;
    padding: 1px 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.input-xs {
    height: 22px;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 1.5; 
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

[image: This shows how it looks like]

Thanks in advance
C.A.

Comment: Please do not use the tag bootstrapping. It is not twitter-bootstrap.

Comment: I removed the tag.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using `<xp:table> ... </xp:table>` for your table.

The white space within the table which you want to reduce is defined for class `.table` as
`padding: 8px`.

Change it this way:

```
.table>thead>tr>th,.table>tbody>tr>th,.table>tfoot>tr>th,
.table>thead>tr>td,.table>tbody>tr>td,.table>tfoot>tr>td
{
    padding: 1px;
}
```