# XPages checkbox style

Tags: checkbox, xpages

I would like to create checkBox with good formating. I used this as you can see in the picture but It doesn't look well. What is the best way to create checkbox to show more than 10 values in it?

https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Multi%20Column%20Controls/screenshots

[image: CheckBox Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just about **css**.

My guess is that you changed relevant css definitions for other parts of your application like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35350388/2065611) and they take effect on this checkbox table now.

Eliminate your css file for a test and look if it works then. If yes, adapt your css definitions so that it works for both cases.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my application, as Knut already mentioned it is a css issues.
My solution
In a theme I have added the following code to style all checkboxes the same

```
<!-- Basic CheckBox -->
    <control>
        <name>CheckBox</name>
        <property>
            <name>styleClass</name>
            <value>btn-checkbox</value>
        </property>
    </control>
```

And in the css I have added the following lines of code

```
.btn-checkbox label{
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

As you can see the problem was in the label of the checkbox.

You can go the theme route, to style all your checkboxes the same way or add it direct to the checkbox with styleClass="btn-checkbox"